# Why is std::atomic<bool> much slower than volatile bool?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11, atomic

I've been using volatile bool for years for thread execution control and it worked fine

```
// in my class declaration
volatile bool stop_;

-----------------

// In the thread function
while (!stop_)
{
     do_things();
}
```

Now, since C++11 added support for atomic operations, I decided to try that instead

```
// in my class declaration
std::atomic<bool> stop_;

-----------------

// In the thread function
while (!stop_)
{
     do_things();
}
```

But it's several orders of magnitude slower than the `volatile bool`!

Simple test case I've written takes about 1 second to complete with `volatile bool` approach. With `std::atomic<bool>` however I've been waiting for about 10 minutes and gave up!

I tried to use `memory_order_relaxed` flag with `load` and `store` to the same effect.

My platform:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- MinGW gcc 4.6.x

What I'm doing wrong?

NB: I know that volatile does not make a variable thread-safe. My question is not about volatile, it's about why atomic is ridiculously slow.

Comment: `assert(your_atomic_variable.is_lock_free())`?

Comment: Your old code is incorrect, it "worked fine" by chance.  Which is better: correct or fast?

Comment: Please post your simple test case (if you want meaningful comments).

Comment: @Mysticial: Unfortunately `volatile` by accident happens to make store and load atomic on x86.

Comment: @aleguna the answer seems to be "because it does different things than `volatile`".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: But for store and load it does not have to do any different thing *on x86-64*.

Comment: @Mystical He never claimed that it was thread-safe or atomic. Are you implying that attempting to replace `volatile` with `std::atomic<bool>` signifies that misunderstanding? Or is it your roundabout way of saying `it does more so why should it not be slower`

Comment: @Dietrich Epp, yes but 1 second vs 10 min? How can it be? Which is why I'm wondering if I'm using atimic correctly

Comment: @JanHudec: Loads and stores of word-aligned types are atomic on almost every platform on the planet, `volatile` or no.  Perhaps you are thinking about memory ordering semantics, which can be used to construct larger atomic operations?

Comment: No. I admit that I jumped to the wrong conclusion. But it's a very common mistake that is made.

Comment: Can you show the generated assembly? That should clear things up

Comment: @Jan [a quick test](http://ideone.com/UoEdoo) on my Windows 7 64 bit system with MinGW GCC 4.7.2 does not show any atomic operations [on the assembly output](http://pastie.org/5136626) (either that, or I'm missing something crucial here).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: On x86 and x86-64 loads and stores are always atomic, caches are kept coherent. They are not necessarily synchronous, but `volatile` prevents reordering by compiler and IIRC x86 does not do any itself.

Comment: Could you please post your real test case (the content of `do_things()`, along with the `main()` function).

Comment: Can you try timing an empty loop "while (___builtin_expect(stop_,0)) { }"? It should be not more than 100ns per iteration, in which case it's an expected timing. Else we'll continue guessing.

Comment: @KennyTM, It's not that easy to do unf as it's a unit test for a large project. But I'll try to extract a self contained test tonight

Comment: Note that C(99?) provides sig_atomic_t. In C it's a type that guarantees write consistency across interupts; POSIX extends the language to cover concurrent writes (eg from threads) as well. I don't know what MinGW does on Windows for it, but it's going to be safe and portable I would have thought, except on the most insane platforms (sig_atomic_t could be a char, if the platform can't provide atomic store/load of a char, well..!)

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, for his old code to be correct he should have to acquire a lock on `stop_`.  But since it is just a true/false check (vs a value check) I can't see how a "spurious" value could make any difference, as long as the variable settles down to a TRUE/FALSE value.  E.g. if it were an `int`, and he were doing `_stop++` on one thread, another thread might see the following number sequence on reading the `_stop` variable, `1`, `9000000`, `2`.  Just to say.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Code from "Olaf Dietsche"

```
 USE ATOMIC
 real   0m1.958s
 user   0m1.957s
 sys    0m0.000s

 USE VOLATILE
 real   0m1.966s
 user   0m1.953s
 sys    0m0.010s
```

**IF YOU ARE USING GCC SMALLER 4.7**

http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html

> Support for atomic operations specifying the C++11/C11 memory model has been added. These new __atomic routines replace the existing __sync built-in routines.
>
> Atomic support is also available for memory blocks. Lock-free instructions will be used if a memory block is the same size and alignment as a supported integer type. Atomic operations which do not have lock-free support are left as function calls. A set of library functions is available on the GCC atomic wiki in the "External Atomics Library" section.

So yeah .. only solution is to upgrade to GCC 4.7

Comment: Well I found the problem (see update), you need to have GCC 4.7+ to have lock-free atomics

Comment: Is there a reasonable limit in milliseconds to how much time the boolean value in question can spend in any modern processor's cache line under one cycle? If I have a guarantee that no multiple accesses are happening under 0.1ms, or let's say 0.001ms, is it safe to assume I'll get expected behavior?

Answer (score 13):

Since I'm curious about this, I tested it myself on Ubuntu 12.04, AMD 2.3 GHz, gcc 4.6.3.

```
#if 1
#include <atomic>
std::atomic<bool> stop_(false);
#else
volatile bool stop_ = false;
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long n = 1000000000;
    while (!stop_) {
        if (--n < 0)
            stop_ = true;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -g -std=c++0x -O3 a.cpp`

Although, same conclusion as @aleguna:

- just `bool`:

> real  0m0.004s
> user  0m0.000s
> sys   0m0.004s

- `volatile bool`:

> $ time ./a.out
> real  0m1.413s
> user  0m1.368s
> sys   0m0.008s

- `std::atomic<bool>`:

> $ time ./a.out
> real  0m32.550s
> user  0m32.466s
> sys   0m0.008s

- `std::atomic<int>`:

> $ time ./a.out
> real  0m32.091s
> user  0m31.958s
> sys   0m0.012s

---

Update 2022-04-10, AMD Ryzen 3 3200G, g++ 9.3.0:

It looks like `atomic` has improved a lot in comparison to volatile.
I increased the loop counter to 10,000,000,000, to have a more precise picture. Although the magnitude doesn't change by this adjustment:

- `std::atomic<bool>`, `std::atomic<int>`: ~2.9s
- `volatile bool`: ~5.4s

Comment: gcc 4.6 atomics are not lock free.  Upgrade to gcc 4.7+

Comment: So, 7-8 years have passed but I just tested your code on ubuntu 20 with g++ 9.4 and the atomic one is 0.773s, the volatile is 0.858s

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Thank you for showing the improvements made by g++, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is an hardware question.
When you write volatile you tell the compiler to not assume anything about the variable but as I understand it the hardware will still treat it as a normal variable. This means that the variable will be in the cache the whole time.
When you use atomic you use special hardware instructions that probably means that the variable is fetch from the main memory each time it is used.
The difference in timing is consistent with this explanation.

Comment: No. The cache is always used.