# Atomic variables on gcc 4.4.6 are extremely slow

Tags: c++

i am using gcc 4.4.6 and atomics can be accessed by `#include <cstdatomic>` . After using them, i realized they are very very slow. Finally i came across a post on stackoverflow, which describes it here [Why is std::atomic<bool> much slower than volatile bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135834/stdatomicbool-is-very-slow)

But i am not able to follow it. Can someone please help me understand that post or explain why atomics in gcc4.4.6 are so slow?

Comment: I don't know about `<stdatomic.h>` (the new C11 atomic functionality), but the C++11 support in GCC 4.4 is generally not very mature. I would guess it would be the same for C11.

Comment: Because they don't use lock-free instructions. As the answer to that linked question said, upgrade to 4.7

Answer (score 2):

I believe that gcc-4.4 was very early in the support for atomics.  The atomics in gcc were recently reworked in gcc-4.7.  I believe this is the first release where different hardware targets were able to use hardware-specific and efficient builtin functions.  In gcc-4.8 a libatomic was provided.  Over the course of 4.7 and 4.8 various platforms have upgraded their atomics support.  The [wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM) explains some of the optimization tradeoffs wit the various memory models when using atomics.

Basically, gcc-4.4 was a bit early.  IIRC even the standard specification for atomics was in flux through gcc-4.7.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `__sync_*` functions in 4.6.3, and not noticed any notable slowness, nor does the assembler code generated show anything untoward. I just updated my project that used to use `__sync_fetch_and_add` to use `std::atomic<>::fetch_add()` - and although it doesn't call the atomic function THAT often, my code showed no difference at all - in single or multi-threaded runs of the code. So I agree with the previous answer: get a newer `gcc`, and it should fix itself.